# Is there an upper bound for k in nearest neighbors-based methods?

Tags: data-mining, unsupervised-learning, outlier, k-nn

When applying a nearest neighbors-based method to a data of, for instance, 2000 points, what is the largest number of neighbors that can be considered ?
I am using a nearest neighbors method in an unsupervised fashion for anomaly detection.

Answer (score 1):

The predicted value by the nearest neighbor algorithm will actually just take the average value of all points that are close to the new point.

It's up to you to find the number of neighbors that you want to consider. If you have 2000 data points, this are the 2000 'neighbors' of which you will select a number of `k` neighbors for taking the average and using that average as prediction.

So the maximum number of `k` is the number of data points in your training set. In your case this is 2000.

Comment: Is there any technique that allows determining the well-performing K ? could this be done manually?

Comment: You can use cross-validation

Comment: @ignatius I don't know if it can help as if I split my data, then I don't know what subset size is most representative of my dataset.

Comment: If you want to know whether your `k` is well performing, you should define what your performance measure is. For this we should understand what problem you are trying to solve. Please give some more detail on this.
Cross-validation is often used to tune hyper parameters. And often this is validated on a test data set which is about 30% of the observations of training data. But again this is a very general remark and it may be irrelevant in your case, especially since you talk about unsupervised methods.

Comment: k-NN is a non parametric method, thus the size of your dataset will have a critical impact on the final performance. You have also to keep in mind the course of dimensionality. What I would do is to configure some experiments: I'd select different sizes of the dataset and for each of them, different number of neighbours. Then, I'd perform cross-validation to have statistical results which can help you evaluate this configurations

Comment: I am using unsupervised methods, however, I have labels in hand so I can take advantage of them and use detection rate as performance measure. Note that I am using a nearest neighbor-based technique for anomaly detection, and not for classification. In fact, I am using LOF for outlier detection, a point is seen as an outlier if it is far from its k nearest neighbors. I am dealing with the curse of dimensionality by using the subspace analysis approach.

Comment: As you are suggesting, I have made an experiment where I select datasets of 2000 points each (that I assume sufficiently representative), and use different values for K (number of nearest neighbors to consider). When conducting my experiment, I was wondering whether there is an upper bound for K, do we lose the notion of neighborhood when using larger values for K (In nearest neighbors methods in general) ? That's what led to my question as it can also help to limit the number of values to consider for K in my experiment.

Comment: It is not clear for me how cross-validation can be applied in this case. It would be appreciated if you could give more details.

Comment: Normally in unsupervised methods you do not have the label. In this case we cannot know whether our classification (as an anomaly or not) is correct or not. But since you have the labels, you can. I would be more tempted to go for a supervised method in this case (classification model). If you still want to do LOF, some easy to implement crossvalidation would be to apply, for each value of k, the algorithm 10 times, each time leaving out 10% of the data. And then for each k take the average accuracy of your classification. Then the k with the best average accuracy will be selected.

Comment: @JoosKorstanje In fact, I want to use the labels in a preprocessing step to learn the well-performing k.  Thank you.